# 3 columns with text newline

Tags: html, css, xhtml

i want to have 2 columns between each other. in the first one should be a background image. with the "minimum" size of the image. the other 2 should have the same size.

If I write a text in it, the `div` should make a newline on his one.

Actually I do it like this

```
  <style type="text/css">
    body
      {
        background-color:#484848;
      }

      #wrapper 
      {
        width: auto;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: inline-block;
      }
     .col 
     {
        display: block;
        background: #FFF;
        float: left;
        height: 200px;
        width:100%;
     }

  </style>
```

---

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="col" style=
    "background-image:url(img/Logo.jpg); 
     width:101px; 
     height:200px;
     background-repeat:no-repeat;"><--! in same line actually -->
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <table border="0">
        <tr>
          <td>username</td>
          <td><input type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>password</td>
          <td><input type="password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><input type="submit" value="login"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      text
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

but it really looks bad...

Comment: if you don't want the break created by 'div' tag, use 'span' tag instead

Comment: i want to break via the div tag but it dont works :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking for something like http://jsfiddle.net/hZPDt/ ?

Please explain what you want exactly

```
body {
  background-color: #484848;
}

#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.col {
  display: block;
  background: #FFF;
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 32.1%;
  margin: .6%;
  background-color: #FF0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6qmvx/

If I understand your question, then the answer is pretty simple - the problem is here:

```
.col {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Remove the % width and add an absolute width, something like this:

```
.col {
    display: block;
    background: #FFF;
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

I have added the border to help illustrate what is going on. Since you are manually overriding the width in the first div, this should work as per your example.